# Source and solution for a problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

Long back i remember having seen a problem like this :Let ${x_i}$ be  a sequence of $n$ positive numbers.Define:$$ x_i^{k+1}=\frac{x_i^k+x_{i+1}^k}{2},i=1,2,,,n;x_{n+1}=x_n$$
The problem was probably asking to prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_i^k=\frac{\sum_1^n x_i}{n}$,with  $x_i^1=x_i.$
Could someone kindly tell me a source of the problem or any book in which I can find it

Comment: What is the value of $x_i^1$

Comment: somebody has posted the same problem here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398377/computing-the-limit-of-a-kind-of-%22mean-value%22-iteration

Comment: but i saw a much simpler proof in some book which i do nor remember